# Problems playing FullHD using HTML Video tag

Tags: html5-video, ajaxuploader

I am using the Ajaxuploader for users to upload videos. Some of them are freezing on playback and I've just realised that it's the FullHD ones. HD plays fine. Is there a way I can force the user to upload in HD only or is there a way to resize on upload? I am using VB.Net for my backend. I'm even trialing a CDN at the moment but it's not making much difference. The video takes a while to start, buffer goes straight up but they still freeze when playing.

```
<video playsinline ID="videoToPlay" poster="https://www.myurl.co.uk/files/images/videoPoster.jpg" runat="server" object-fit:contain autoplay preload class="videosize" controls>
    <source src="vid1.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, opus"'/> 
    <source src="vid2.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
<source src="video/video.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
</video>


videoToPlay.src="https://myurl.b-cdn.net/" & session("video")
```

Comment: on upload you could feed them through something like ffmpeg to convert then to a more optimized format for streaming (either single bitrate mp4, or an adaptive format like HLS or Dash) - it will mean the video won't be available as soon as uploaded, but give you more control over the playback experience. You could also upload to something like CloudFlare or Video-API and let them worry about it...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The delay of the video being available will be a big concern on this particular site so I didn't really want to go down that route. Should a Full HD video play back ok as it is or should it be optimized? I was also wondering about the possibility of storing the videos with super fast video host and then pointing to them from a subdomain.. Does that makes sense?

Comment: FullHD (1080p) should be playable without problems but there are some considerations around optimization (eg position of the metatdata in the file, efficiency of encoding etc). Optimized host (eg Cloudflare) would be good but I'd suggest a background optimization that replaces the original asset with adaptive version for better longer term playback experience